# Core Data iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have method that returned `NSManagedObject` and I don't know what kind of `NSManagedObject` it is, because depend of situation this method can return 1 of 3 kind of classes which mark as `NSManagedObject`. So how can I understand which kind of `NSManagedObject` it return? For example: firstObj, secondObj, thirdObj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query its entity name you can simply do this:

```
//Here myObj is your NSManagedObject instance
NSString *entityName  = [[myObj entity] name];
```

Now if you like further information you could do something like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *desc = [myObj entity];
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [desc managedObjectModel]; //The managed object model
NSString *className = [desc managedObjectClassName]; //The class name
etc..
```

For more information see the docs on `NSEntityDescription` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like:

```
[obj isKindOfClass: [Subclass class]]
```

Comment: This will not work with plain NSManagedObjects. LightNight never told he was using custom classes.

Comment: He says: "depend of situation this method can return 1 of 3 kind of classes". To me that means he has one of three kinds of classes?